# How to use the rate in AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, swift, rate, avaudioengine

How do we use rate in AVAudioEngine?

Here's my complete code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("music", ofType: "wav"){

        var filePathURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
        audioEngine.attachNode(myPlayer)
        var audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: filePathURL, error: nil)
        var audioError:NSError?

        audioEngine.connect(myPlayer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFile.processingFormat)

        myPlayer.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&audioError)

    }else {
        println("url not found")

    }

}


@IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {

    myPlayer.rate = 0.5
    myPlayer.play()

}
```

So while I play the sound its not using the rate at at all. Furthermore, how do I reset the position once I am done playing the audio. AVAudioPlayer had currentTime to use to reset the bar.

Edit1: This is rather confusing cause if AVAudioPlayerNode doesn't have a class to maintain why does it allow me to use rate at all? Sorry completely noob to programming.

Edit2: Got it working with help from Matt's example code. I missed the audio output line:

```
        var audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        var myPlayer = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        audioEngine.attachNode(myPlayer)
        var changeAudioUnitTime = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()

        changeAudioUnitTime.rate = audioChangeNumber
        audioEngine.attachNode(changeAudioUnitTime)
        audioEngine.connect(myPlayer, to: changeAudioUnitTime, format: nil)
        audioEngine.connect(changeAudioUnitTime, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)
        audioPlayerNode.play()
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To change the rate with AVAudioEngine, you have two choices:

- Do 3D mixing with an AVAudioEnvironmentNode. Only the AVAudioEnvironmentNode has a meaningful AVAudio3DMixing protocol `rate` property.
- Pass the file output through an AVAudioUnitTimePitch node and adjust its `rate`.

Comment: I demonstrate the second approach here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p655AVAudioEngineTest/AVAudioEngineTest/ViewController.swift

Comment: Matt, I tried your example code by changing only the rate and attaching the node. Following it by scheduling the file and trying to play it. There is always an error "uncaught exception of type NSException". So I checked my storyboard to see if there were any unchecked buttons or connections. There weren't any. So I tried removing the effect part and re-playing it. That part works.

Comment: The example works as I wrote it; what you did in your code, I've no idea. However, that's irrelevant; you asked why `rate` wasn't working and how to make it work, and I told you.